# strpos with array_key_search

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

i have a code to search for array keys, but only if the message is the exact message, i want it to use strpos so it can detect the message but i don't know how to do it:

My Code:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$responses = array("hi" => "whats up?");
if (array_key_exists($message,$responses)){
$msg = strtolower($message);
$answer = $responses[$msg];
echo $answer;
}
```

So this only works if the whole posted data was "hi". I want it to use strpos so  it can detect hi anywhere, how would i do that?

Comment: This "strpos" has made me confused :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but is this what you want?

```
$foundKey = null;
foreach ($responses as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($message, $key) !== false) {
        $foundKey = $key;
        break;
    }
}
if ($foundKey !== null) {
    echo "Found key: " . $responses[$key];
}
```

**Edit**:

If you want a case insensitive version, of course you can use this instead:

```
$foundKey = null;
foreach ($responses as $key => $value) {
    if (stripos($message, $key) !== false) {
        $foundKey = strtolower($key);
        break;
    }
}
if ($foundKey !== null) {
    echo "Found key: " . $responses[$key];
}
```

Comment: Perfect - remember to accept the answer, so others will see the comment on the top of the thread if the search for the same: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

strpos(firststring,secondstring,startposition[Optional]) function  is return num.if num>=0 mean second string in first string.

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$responses = array("hi" => "whats up?");
if (strpos($message,$responses)>=0){
$msg = strtolower($message);
$answer = $responses[$msg];
echo $answer;
}
```